# DIV not working with different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This might have been answered before, my searching hasn't led me to any answers, so I apologize in advance if there's already a thread that might be able to help.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8GKA/1/embedded/result/)

I realize that what the page looks wonky, it looks much better from my own PC. I'm really just having trouble with the navbar not centering on the slideshow when it comes to differing resolutions.

HTML:

```
</div>
<div id="schedule">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="PDFs/2014/LHS Course Catalog 2013-2014.pdf">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Faculty.html">Faculty</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Programs.html">Programs and Athletics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Information &#9661;</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="https://parentlink.ccsd.net/html/ContentBase/Content/Home/Login">ParentLink</a>
                </li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                </li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Handouts.html">Important Handouts</a>

            </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="slide_background">
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section id=wowslider-container4 -->
    <div id="wowslider-container4">
        <div class="ws_images">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="#" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_bullets">


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine4//wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine4//script.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
background-image:url(images/images/banner_repeat_01.jpg);
width:auto;
height:auto;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
footer {
background-color:#c3c3c3;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
width:100%;
left:0;
right:0;
position:absolute;
}
#banner {
width:auto;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
color:white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#schedule {
color:white;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
margin-top:2.9em;
}
#slide_background {
background-color:#c3c3c3;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}
#slides {
background-color:#000;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
height:13em;
width:70%;
margin-top:-1em;
color:white;
}
#frontpage {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
color:#333;
margin-top:23em;
}
#banner hr {
width:15em;
margin-top:-1.8em
}
#frontpage table th {
color:#333;
border-collapse:collapse;
font-size:2em;
text-decoration:underline;
font-variant:small-caps;
}
#frontpage table td {
color:#161616;
border-collapse:collapse;
font-size:1.3em;
}
h1 {
font-size:2.8em;
margin-top:-.1em;
}
h3 {
font-variant:small-caps;
margin-top:-.2em;
letter-spacing:4px;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:black;
}
a:active {
text-decoration:underline;
color: #00F;
}
table a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
color:#33F;
}
a h3 {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
a h1 {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
table {
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:1em;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
letter-spacing:2px;
margin-top:-.5em;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
#frontpage td:nth-child(3) {
border-right:none;
}
.schedule_day {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.3em;
text-decoration:underline;
color:black;
font-variant:small-caps;
}
#banner a h1 {
text-decoration: none;
}

#wowslider-container4 {
zoom: 1;
position: relative;
max-width:960px;
margin:0px auto 0px;
z-index:90;
border:none;
text-align:left;
/* reset align=center */
font-size: 10px;
}
* html #wowslider-container4 {
width:960px
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images ul {
position:relative;
width: 10000%;
height:auto;
left:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-spacing:0;
overflow: visible;
/*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images ul li {
width:1%;
line-height:0;
/*opera*/
float:left;
font-size:0;
padding:0 0 0 0 !important;
margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images {
position: relative;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images a {
width:100%;
display:block;
color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container4 img {
max-width: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images img {
width:100%;
border:none 0;
max-width: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#wowslider-container4 a {
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
border: none;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets {
font-size: 0px;
float: left;
position:absolute;
z-index:70;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets div {
position:relative;
float:left;
}
#wowslider-container4 .wsl {
display:none;
}
#wowslider-container4 sound, #wowslider-container4 object {
position:absolute;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets {
padding: 9px;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets a {
width:11px;
height:11px;
background: url(./bullet.png) left top;
float: left;
text-indent: -4000px;
position:relative;
margin-left:5px;
color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets a:hover {
background-position: 0 50%;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets a.ws_selbull {
background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container4 a.ws_next, #wowslider-container4 a.ws_prev {
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:50%;
margin-top:-2em;
z-index:60;
height: 4.5em;
width: 4.5em;
background-image: url(./arrows.png);
opacity: 0.8;
background-size: 200%;
}
#wowslider-container4 a.ws_next {
background-position: 100% 0;
right:2.1em;
}
#wowslider-container4 a.ws_prev {
left:2.1em;
background-position: 0 0;
}
#wowslider-container4 a.ws_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
#wowslider-container4 a.ws_prev:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
/*playpause*/
#wowslider-container4 .ws_playpause {
display:none;
width: 4.5em;
height: 4.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -2em;
margin-top: -2em;
z-index: 59;
background-size: 100%;
}
#wowslider-container4:hover .ws_playpause {
display:block;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_pause {
background-image: url(./pause.png);
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_play {
background-image: url(./play.png);
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_pause:hover, #wowslider-container1 .ws_play:hover {
background-position: 100% 100% !important;
}
/* bottom center */
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets {
bottom: -26px;
left:862px;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_bullets div {
left:-50%;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws-title {
position:absolute;
display:block;
bottom: 1.7em;
left: 0;
margin: 0.9em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0.9em;
padding:0.8em;
background:#FFFFFF;
color:#5D5D5D;
z-index: 50;
font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-radius:0.5em;
-moz-border-radius:0 1em 1em 0;
border-radius:0 1em 1em 0;
opacity:0.8;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #5D5D5D;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #5D5D5D;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws-title div {
padding-top:0.25em;
font-size: 1.4em;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws-title span {
font-size: 1.8em;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images ul {
animation: wsBasic 20s infinite;
-moz-animation: wsBasic 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation: wsBasic 20s infinite;
}
@keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
    left:-0%
}
10% {
    left:-0%
}
20% {
    left:-100%
}
30% {
    left:-100%
}
40% {
    left:-200%
}
50% {
    left:-200%
}
60% {
    left:-300%
}
70% {
    left:-300%
}
80% {
    left:-400%
}
90% {
    left:-400%
}
}
@-moz-keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
    left:-0%
}
10% {
    left:-0%
}
20% {
    left:-100%
}
30% {
    left:-100%
}
40% {
    left:-200%
}
50% {
    left:-200%
}
60% {
    left:-300%
}
70% {
    left:-300%
}
80% {
    left:-400%
}
90% {
    left:-400%
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
    left:-0%
}
10% {
    left:-0%
}
20% {
    left:-100%
}
30% {
    left:-100%
}
40% {
    left:-200%
}
50% {
    left:-200%
}
60% {
    left:-300%
}
70% {
    left:-300%
}
80% {
    left:-400%
}
90% {
    left:-400%
}
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_images img {
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
}
#wowslider-container4 .ws_effect img {
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
}

#wrap {
width: 100%;
/* Spans the width of the page */
height: 3.8em;
margin: 0;
/* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
z-index: 99;
/* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
position: absolute;
background-color:#FFF;
left:-3px;
right:0;
top: 153px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
   .navbar {
height: .5em;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 40em;
margin-right: auto;
position: absolute;
/* Ensures that the menu doesn't affect other elements */
width: auto;
left: 0 top: 0px;
min-width:800px;
}
.navbar li {
height: 1.5em;
;
width: 10em;
/* Each menu item is 150px wide */
float:left;
text-align: center;
/* All text is placed in the center of the box */
list-style: none;
/* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
font:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:1em;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
border-left:thin solid #000;
border-right:thin solid #000;
}
 .navbar a {
padding: 0;
/* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
text-decoration: none;
/* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
color: #000;
/* Text color is white */
display: block;
}
.navbar li ul {
display: none;
/* Hides the drop-down menu */
height: auto;
margin: 0;
/* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
}
.navbar li:hover ul {
display: block;
/* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
border: none;
padding: .7em;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
.navbar li ul li {
border:none;
background-color:#CCC;
border:thin solid #000;
padding:5px;
width:130px;
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add this to your #wrap id

   ```
   #wrap { text-align: center; }
   ```
2. and remove your .navbar code. paste this instead

   ```
   .navbar { display: inline-block; }
   ```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Spsb/1/)

Comment: Hey Isaac, thank you for the help! That worked previously, but I've since added more links on my navbar, and now my navbar breaks and creates two rows. My code is 99% the same as above, just with a few more nav-links. Do you think you could help?

Comment: That's correct. you can use drop down menu when screen size is mobile size or tablet size.

Answer (score -1):

Hy Harin

If I understood you right, it's all about centering the navigation?
then try these:

```
.navbar {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

set a fixed with of your navbar UL. then set a margin: 0 auto. that means 0 margin on top and bottom and auto margin on the left and right side = it will be centered.
this won't work correctly, if the screen width is smaler than 800px ;)

Comment: yes it does ;) just add my css property at the end of your fiddle and retry it. the width of the preview window must be higher than 800px! else the navbar li items will break in multiple lines

Comment: not working. be aware that this is responsive layout